# How do I refresh just one div in html?

Tags: html, css

I currently have this line in my code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $dataInterval ?>" >
```

The problem is that it refreshes my whole site. I would like it to just refresh one specific div section on my site which is a chart that pulls data from a file.

Comment: To refresh perticular div u need to give ajax call and then update the content of the Div you want to refresh

Comment: You should learn about `ajax`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it with plain HTML and CSS. You have to use Ajax for this. An example would be the `.load()` function in jQuery:

```
$(".element").load(location.href + " .element > *");
```

This will load the content of `.element` inside of itself.

For example you can use it with a timeout to reload periodically:

```
setTimeout('ReloadPage()', 60000);

function ReloadPage() {
    $(".element").load(location.href + " .element > *");
}
```

This will reload the content of `.element` every 60 seconds.